# javascript set variable from .text method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in javascript development and I want to ask how to set variable from text method.

Example: in this code have a text method

```
        $('.phone').text(theRestaurant.phone);
        $('.location').text(theRestaurant.location);
        $('.info').text(theRestaurant.info);
```

in the Html file, when I create any class from these will print the value from JSON file.

Example :

```
        <div class='phone'></div>
```

Output: (000)000-9999

source code:

```
        <div class='phone'>(000)000-9999</div>
```

I try to set this in variable but it doesn't work.

My try:

```
        var phone = theRestaurant.phone
```

I want to set it in variable because I need to put it inside href value like so:

```
<script>
    var phone = 'tel:' + phone
    document.getElementById("phone").href = phone;
</script>
```

I hope everything clear. and If have an other solution please tell about it.

Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("phone").href = phone` ? *(You wrote `ByID`)*

Comment: Ok, now when I type in console: phone, it give me <h6 id="phone">744-xxxxxx</h6>

I set the style for h6 display:none

can I put the value of h6 in side href="tel:__number_here__"

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with same ID. But considering you have `<a class="phone">`, you can do:  `var phone=document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML;`  
`document.getElementsByClassName("phone")[0].href = phone;`

Comment: You are 100% right, but that if I type manually in id class it works, but because the data coms from json, it give me empty value

Comment: can you `console.log(theRestaurant.phone);` ? and see what it gets

Comment: Its works now, I put it in the main file. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer came from @itsgoingdown

this code in main javascript file:

```
var phone=document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML; document.getElementsByClassName("phone")[0].href = phone;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you wrapped your jQuery code in a `document.ready()` wrapper?

If not, then the javascript might run before the page has had time to create the elements in the DOM, and nothing will work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     //all javascript/jQuery code goes in here
});
</script>
```

Also, see my comment above about mixing up "ByClassName" and "ByID"

Comment: the reason of my question that how to store the data in variable.
I know that I type by id, but even if I set by class doesn't work

Comment: when I type in the browser console:  phone, it give me error